# Synchronized "call-order-aware" method returning value

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a method that sends 3 web requests to a device, which makes it send a sms.
The 2 first requests respectively set the sms recipient and message body. The third triggers the dispatch.

It's clear that this method has to be synchronized, since race calls will completely mess up the sms configuration process.

It is of course very nicely solvable this way :

```
private object _smsLock  
private bool SendSmsSync(string recipientNumber, string body)  
{  
    lock(_smsLock)  
    {  
        // 3 web requests are sent here  
        // false is returned if something goes wrong
        return true;
    }  
}
```

However, this solution's downside is that we have absolutely no control on the order in which simultaneous calls will proceed.

A heavy piece of code including a Queue, ManualResetEvents, and threads could of course make it. But I still would like to know if someone is aware of an easier way to do it.

Discuss :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable way to protect the sending of a message.  It will prevent the messages themselves from going out of order.

If you need to synchronize across multiple messages, one option would be to use a producer/consumer scenario.  This would allow you to have a single thread that does nothing but pump these messages out, in order.

```
public class Sms
{
    public class SmsMessage
    {
        public int RecipientNumber { get; private set; }
        public string Body { get; private set; }
        public Sms(int recipient, string body) 
        { 
           this.RecipientNumber = recipient;
           this.Body = body;
        }
    }

    // Include your code above...

    private BlockingCollection<SmsMessage> messageQueue = new BlockingCollection<SmsMessage>();

     public void Send(SmsMessage message)
     {
           messageQueue.Add(message);
     }

     // Permanently stop sending messages...
     public void Stop()
     {
           messageQueue.CompleteAdding();
     }

     public Sms()
     {
         // Spawn a thread to pump messages as they arrive
         Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
             {
                  foreach(var message in messageQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                      SendSmsSync(message.RecipientNumber, message.Body);
             }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
     }
}
```

With this, you could just create an Sms instance, and call Send to enqueue a message.  Messages will always get sent in order.

Also, this should eliminate the need for the locking above since the messages are always sent in a single consumer thread.

Comment: Thank you for leading me towards System.Threading.Tasks, which I had never heard of (shame on me !).

Comment: @Remy: BTW, if you want details, I have a **long** series on TPL (that and related namespaces) at: http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most logical answer should surely be "don't do that".

That is: If you need to make three calls in sequence*, don't put them on seperate threads - just write the code sequentially.

(* Ok, so the first and second *could* be parallelised, but why?)

Comment: I don't want the three calls to be on seperate threads, au contraire !  The scenario is that my SendSms method can be accessed by several threads simultaneously.  Sorry if I misexplained myself.